# I don't understand why it occurred. Uncaught TypeError: Failed due to illegal value in property: รูป

Tags: html, google-apps-script

It is Google Apps Script for uploading files to Drive with the ability to continuously add input, and it is encountering an Uncaught TypeError: Failed due to an illegal value in the property: "รูป" const col3 = document.createElement('div');I would like to have an example of how to fix this.

Google Apps Script

```
function saveFormData(formData) {
  // เปิด Google Sheets ที่คุณต้องการบันทึกข้อมูลลงไป
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxx').getActiveSheet();

  // สร้างชุดข้อมูลใหม่
  var newData = [];

  // วนลูปผ่านข้อมูลที่ส่งมาจากแบบฟอร์ม HTML
  for (var i = 0; i < formData.length; i++) {
    var data = formData[i];
    newData.push([data['ลำดับ'], data['รายการ'], data['รูป'], data['หมายเหตุ']]);
  }

  // บันทึกข้อมูลลงใน Google Sheets
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}

function doPost(e) {
  var formData = e.parameter; // รับข้อมูลจากแบบฟอร์ม
  var destinationId = 'xxx'; // ระบุ ID ของโฟลเดอร์ที่คุณต้องการบันทึกไฟล์

  // ตรวจสอบว่ามีไฟล์ถูกอัปโหลดหรือไม่
  if (formData.fileUpload) {
    var fileBlob = e.parameters.fileUpload[0]; // เรียก Blob ของไฟล์ที่ถูกอัปโหลด
    var fileName = fileBlob.getName();

    // บันทึกไฟล์ลงใน Google Drive โดยระบุโฟลเดอร์ปลายทาง
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationId);
    var file = folder.createFile(fileBlob);

    // ส่งข้อมูลการอัปโหลดไฟล์กลับเป็นการตอบรับ
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('ไฟล์ถูกอัปโหลดเรียบร้อยแล้ว').setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  } else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('ไม่มีไฟล์ถูกอัปโหลด');
  }
}
```

html

```
<html>
<body>
    <form class="form body" id="myForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); saveForm();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="input-box">
            <div id="dynamicInputs"></div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-add" onclick="addInputField()">เพิ่มงาน</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-add" onclick="deleteLastInputField()">ลบงานล่าสุด</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-add" onclick="deleteAllInputFields()">ลบทั้งหมด</button>
        </div>
        <div class="gender-box">
            <label>จำนวนงานที่เพิ่ม: <span id="inputCount">0</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="gender-box">
            <label>ประเภทงาน</label>
            <div class="gender-option">
                <div class="gender">
                    <div id="checkboxOptions" class="checkbox-options" required></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="บันทึกข้อมูล">
        </div>
    </form>
```

**javascript**

```
    <script>
        var inputCount = 0;
        function addInputField() {
            const dynamicInputs = document.getElementById('dynamicInputs');
            const rowContainer = document.createElement('div');
            rowContainer.className = 'row g-3';
            const col1 = document.createElement('div');
            col1.className = 'col-sm';
            col1.innerHTML = `<input type="text" class="form-control inp" value="${inputCount + 1}" readonly>`;
            const col2 = document.createElement('div');
            col2.className = 'col-sm-7';
            const inputField1 = document.createElement('input');
            inputField1.type = 'text';
            inputField1.className = 'form-control inp'; // เพิ่มคลาส 'inp' สำหรับ input fields
            inputField1.placeholder = 'รายการ';
            inputField1.setAttribute('aria-label', 'รายการ');
            col2.appendChild(inputField1);
            const col3 = document.createElement('div');
            col3.className = 'col-sm';
            const inputField2 = document.createElement('input');
            inputField2.type = 'file';
            inputField2.className = 'form-control inp'; // เพิ่มคลาส 'inp' สำหรับ input fields
            inputField2.placeholder = 'รูป';
            inputField2.setAttribute('aria-label', 'รูป');
            col3.appendChild(inputField2);
            const col4 = document.createElement('div');
            col4.className = 'col-sm';
            const inputField3 = document.createElement('input');
            inputField3.type = 'text';
            inputField3.className = 'form-control inp'; // เพิ่มคลาส 'inp' สำหรับ input fields
            inputField3.placeholder = 'หมายเหตุ';
            inputField3.setAttribute('aria-label', 'หมายเหตุ');
            col4.appendChild(inputField3);
            rowContainer.id = `input${inputCount}`;
            rowContainer.appendChild(col1);
            rowContainer.appendChild(col2);
            rowContainer.appendChild(col3);
            rowContainer.appendChild(col4);
            dynamicInputs.appendChild(rowContainer);
            inputCount++;
            document.getElementById('inputCount').innerText = inputCount;
        }

        function deleteLastInputField() {
            if (inputCount > 0) {
                inputCount--;
                const dynamicInputs = document.getElementById('dynamicInputs');
                const lastRowContainer = document.getElementById(`input${inputCount}`);
                if (lastRowContainer) {
                    lastRowContainer.remove();
                }
                const lastDeleteButton = dynamicInputs.lastElementChild;
                if (lastDeleteButton && lastDeleteButton.classList.contains('btn-delete')) {
                    lastDeleteButton.remove();
                }
                document.getElementById('inputCount').innerText = inputCount;
            }
        }
        function deleteAllInputFields() {
            const dynamicInputs = document.getElementById('dynamicInputs');
            dynamicInputs.innerHTML = ''; // ลบทุก input ที่เพิ่มไว้
            inputCount = 0; // รีเซ็ต inputCount เป็น 0
            document.getElementById('inputCount').innerText = inputCount; // อัปเดตการแสดงจำนวนงานที่เพิ่ม
        }
        function saveForm() {
          const dynamicInputs = document.getElementById('dynamicInputs');
          const rows = dynamicInputs.getElementsByClassName('row g-3');
          const tasks = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            const row = rows[i];
            const columns = row.getElementsByTagName('input');
            const task = {
              ลำดับ: columns[0].value,
              รายการ: columns[1].value,
              รูป: selectedFile, // ใช้ selectedFile แทน columns[2].files[0]
              หมายเหตุ: columns[3].value,
            };
            tasks.push(task);
          }
          google.script.run.saveFormData(tasks);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Yunnosch Most of the question is HTML code and the opening code fence was missing.

Comment: @Rubén Oh, I see. But now you probably helped them around the minimum of non-code explanation prose...

Comment: What : You should describe what the code does before including the it. As this is an HTML file, you should mention if you have added it to a web server or if you are opening it as a local file, and if the error is shown in the JavaScript console or in another place.

Comment: You should remove `your text` after `<script>`.

Answer (score 0):

The `saveForm` function assigns an object to the `tasks` variable. On the object declaration, it calls the `selectFile` variable, but your code didn't declare it. Because of this, the property `รูป` gets assigned `null`. According to the error message, this is an invalid value.

Comment: I would like to have an example of how to fix this.